# getmonth() is not a function error parsing date

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a `production_date` which I'm trying to extract year and month but I keep getting `getMonth()` and `getYear()` is not a function error...

```
function(d) { 
          var dt = d.production_date
          var dtm = dt.getMonth();
          var dty = dt.getYear();
          return dtm + "/" + dty 
       }
```

Comment: It means that `d.production_date` isn't a date object.

Comment: `var dt = new Date(d.production_date);`

Comment: Post your `d` object

Comment: If it's passed over network, you'll only have a number (timestamp)

Comment: @gr3g that worked...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function(d) { 
          var dt = new Date(d.production_date);
          var dtm = dt.getMonth();
          var dty = dt.getFullYear();
          return dtm + "/" + dty 
       }
```

If it's passed over network, you'll only have a number (timestamp)

Comment: one thing on this...2017 shows up as 117, 2016 shows up as 116 with getYear()...any idea why that happens?

Comment: my date with `new Date(d.production_date)` looks like this....`"Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)"`

Comment: [Use `getFullYear()`, `getYear()` is deprecated (year 2000 problem)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear).

Comment: Thank you.  I can't tell you how many times this sort of thing has bitten me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that is a valid date.
If it is a string ,you can convert it into date using new Date("datestring"),make sure that datestring is in the following format 
"YYYY/MM/DD" ,if so you can do it as the following

```js
var d = {
  "production_date": "2016/11/23"
}
var val = getMonthYear(d);
console.log(val);

function getMonthYear(d) {
  var dt = new Date(d.production_date);
  var dtm = dt.getMonth();
  var dty = dt.getYear();
  return dtm + "/" + dty
}
```

Hope it helps