# Parsing a date object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have component..

```
<DayActivity
    days={[
      {
        resort: 'Whistler',
        date: new Date('2/25/2018'),
        powder: true,
        backcountry: true,
      },
```

I map over it in the component DayActivity and pass the result to another component...

```
{days.map((day, i) => <SkiDayRow key={i} {...day} />)}
```

In  I am unable to call date.getMonth()

```
export const SkiDayRow = ({ resort, date, powder, backcountry }) => (
  <div>
    <tr>
      <td>{date.getMonth()}</td>
```

I understand that I am getting a timestamp,

[getmonth() is not a function error parsing date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751111/getmonth-is-not-a-function-error-parsing-date)

but I am not sure how to work this out in my case.

Comment: `{new Date(date).getMonth()}`??

Comment: Something is missing in your example, it works fine if I just recreate the component https://codesandbox.io/s/6jp5j7vq8n

Comment: getting me closer this...{new Date(date).getMonth()}/ {new Date(date).getYear()} / {new Date(date).getFullYear()} yields this...1/NaN/2018

Comment: @Axnyff I get in error in your codesandbox

Comment: Fixed [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv4mlvl1l0) by @Axnyff by forking. `SkiDayRow` wasn't implemented there and it's actually working w/o a problem

Comment: thanks all for the help, fixed, now to wipe egg off my face.